# Call to a member function fill() on string

Tags: php, laravel, oop

I got this error after trying to edit my data. 
FatalErrorException in CRUDRenderHelper.php line 41: Call to a member function fill() on string

my CarCategoriesController code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Models\CarCategory;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Yajra\Datatables\Datatables;
use App\Http\Controllers\Base\MasterController;
use Route;
use Illuminate\View\View;

class CarCategoriesController extends MasterController
{
protected $indexView = 'CarCategories.index';
protected $createView = 'CarCategories.create';
protected $editView = 'CarCategories.create';
protected $routeBindModel = 'CarCategories'; //Route Model Binding name in   RouteServiceProvider
protected $redirectPageWhenFormSuccess = 'CarCategories.index'; //Route Name
protected $title = 'Car Categories';

public function save(Request $request, $obj = null) {

if (!$obj) {
    $obj = new CarCategory;
}
return $this->saveHandler($request, $obj);
}

//Must have this method if need datatable;
public function datatableBuilder($obj = null) {
return CarCategory::query();
} 
}
```

CRUDRenderHelper code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers\Traits;

use App\Helpers\Exceptions\ValidationException;
use App\Helpers\SessionHelper;
use DB;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laracasts\Flash\flash;
use Yajra\Datatables\Datatables;
use Illuminate\View\View; 


trait CRUDRenderHelper
{
public function render(View $view, $route = null, $obj = null, $method = 'POST') {
$title = $this->title;
$appName = $this->appName;
$action = $this->action;
return $view->with(compact('title', 'appName', 'route', 'obj', 'method', 'action'));
}

public function getFormRoute($obj = null) {

if ($obj) {
    $route = property_exists($this, 'updateFormRouteName') ? 
                $this->updateFormRouteName : $this-  >routeBindModel.'.update';
    return route($route, [$this->routeBindModel => $obj]);
}
$route = property_exists($this, 'saveFormRouteName') ? 
            $this->saveFormRouteName : $this->routeBindModel.'.store';
return route($route);
}

public function saveHandler(Request $request, $obj) {

try {

    DB::beginTransaction();
    $obj->fill($request->all());
    if (!$obj->save()) {
        throw new ValidationException($obj->errors());
    }
    DB::commit();
    return $this->sendSuccessResponse($request);
} catch (ValidationException $e) {
    DB::rollback();
    \Log::error($e->errors);
    return $this->sendErrorResponse($request, $e->errors);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();
    \Log::error($e->getMessage());
    return $this->sendErrorResponse($request,'Unable to process. Please contact system Administrator');
}

}

public function sendErrorResponse(Request $request, $errors) {

if ($request->ajax()) {
    return response($errors, 400);
}
SessionHelper::setMessage($errors, 'danger');
return back()->withInput()->withErrors($errors);

}

public function sendSuccessResponse(Request $request) {

if ($request->ajax()) {
    return response('Success', 200);
}

flash('Process Successfully', 'success');

if (property_exists($this, 'redirectPageWhenFormSuccess')) {
    return redirect()->route($this->redirectPageWhenFormSuccess);
}

return back();
}

public function save(Request $request) {

return $this->saveHandler($request, $obj);
}

public function delete(Request $request, $obj) {

if (!$obj->delete()) {
    throw new ValidationException($obj->errors());
}
return $this->sendSuccessResponse($request);
}

/**
* [datatableBuilder Build model query here]
* @return [Object] [Laravel Eloquent Model]
*/
public function datatableBuilder($obj = null) {}

public function makeDatatable($obj) {

return Datatables::of($obj)
->addColumn('action', function ($model) {
        return $this->makeActionButtonsForDatatable($model);
})
->make(true);
}

/**
* [makeActionButtonsForDatatable Make buttons for datatables]
* @param  [Object] $model [Eloquent Model]
* @return [string]        [HTML script]
*/
public function makeActionButtonsForDatatable($model) {
$routeShow = property_exists($this, 'showRouteName') ? 
            $this->showRouteName : $this->routeBindModel.'.show';
$routeEdit = property_exists($this, 'editRouteName') ? 
            $this->editRouteName : $this->routeBindModel.'.edit';
$routeDelete = property_exists($this, 'deleteRouteName') ? 
            $this->deleteRouteName : $this->routeBindModel.'.destroy';
return '

    <a href="'.route($routeEdit, [$this->routeBindModel => $model->id]).'"
        class="btn btn-warning btn-xs edit">
        <span class="fa fa-pencil"></span> Edit
    </a>
    <a id="delBtn" data-url="'.route($routeDelete, [$this->routeBindModel => $model->id]).'"
        data-toggle="modal" data-target=" #modalDelete" data-title="Confirmation" data-table-name="#datatable" data-message="Do you want to delete this record?" 
        class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete" >
        <span class="fa fa-trash-o"></span> Delete
    </a>';
}

protected function setAction($string) {

$this->action = $string;
return $this;
}

}
```

any idea ?

Comment: Where are you calling the `CarCategoriesController->save()` method?

Comment: @Doom5 at CarCategoriesController public function save(Request $request, $obj = null) {

if (!$obj) {
    $obj = new CarCategory;
}
return $this->saveHandler($request, $obj);
}

Comment: No. That is where it's defined. Your `save()` method is probably being passed a string, which in turn is being passed to `saveHandler()`. Are you perhaps setting it as an action for a route? Can you check the value of `$obj` inside your `save()` method. You can use `dd($obj);`.

Comment: @Doom5 it only show the id of my data : "11"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a route like this:

```
Route::post('car_category/{id}', 'CarCategoriesController@save');
```

You are receiving the an id from your route. By default, they are being passed to your controller methods as strings. In your code, you are passing the id, which is a string, to your `saveHandler()` method. That is why `$obj->fill()` on line 41 of your `CRUDRenderHelper` is throwing an exception.

Change your `save` method to check if `$id` is not null and if it is, create a new CarCategory and if not, then try to fetch it from the database using the given `$id`:

```
public function save(Request $request, $id = null)
{
    $obj = null;

    if ($id === null) {
        $obj = new CarCategory;
    } else {
        $obj = CarCategory::findOrFail($id);
    }

    return $this->saveHandler($request, $obj);
}
```

Comment: It's working, how it works I mean can u explain it  ??
and why my code doesn't working ..

Comment: should I do the same to delete it ?
delete()on string.

Comment: Is it a method on your `CarCategoriesController` too? Are you checking `$obj` the same way you are checking it on your `save()` method and passing it to the `delete()` method provided by your trait? If so, then you should change it too.

Comment: Yeah it's method and passing to saveHandler ().